# D3D12: Can we really not have a 1-dimensional buffer/texture of size > 25000?

Tags: shader, hlsl, directx-12

So, what I actually want is rather simple in theory, but I can't get it to work in practice.

I simply want read and write access to a dynamically-sized array of floats from (raytracing) shaders. I think the right thing is to declare this array as an UAV.

However, I've tried to declare it as a `RWTexture1D<float>` as well as a `RWBuffer<float>`. But for both I'm receiving the error that the dimension is too large. The dimension I specified was around 100k, but it seems like `RWBuffer<float>` is limited to 25k and `RWTexture1D<float>` is limited to 16384. What can I do?

*EDIT*: This is the code:

```
    D3D12_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC unordered_access_view_desc{};
    unordered_access_view_desc.Buffer.NumElements = 100000;
    unordered_access_view_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
    unordered_access_view_desc.ViewDimension = D3D12_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    
    d3d.device->CreateUnorderedAccessView(resource, nullptr, &unordered_access_view_desc, handle);
```

and the error:

> The Dimensions of the View are invalid due to at least one of the following conditions. Assuming this Format (0x29, R32_FLOAT), FirstElement (value = 0) must be between 0 and the maximum offset of the Buffer, 24999, inclusively.

I don't get this. If the format would be `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` instead and I would choose `Buffer.NumElements = 25000` I would end up with allocating the same amount of memory.

But even when I use this hack, is it really not possible to create a 1-dimensional array of size > 25000? Even a simple 2-dimensional texture of size 512x512 has more values (262144). Do I really need to create such a 2-dimensional texture and reindex appropriately?

---

**EDIT**: This is the code with `CreateBuffer` I'm using:

```
D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapDesc = {};
heapDesc.Type = D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT;
heapDesc.CreationNodeMask = 1;
heapDesc.VisibleNodeMask = 1;

D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC resourceDesc = {};
resourceDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
resourceDesc.Height = 1;
resourceDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
resourceDesc.MipLevels = 1;
resourceDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
resourceDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
resourceDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
resourceDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR;
resourceDesc.Width = /* ... */;
resourceDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_UNORDERED_ACCESS;

device->CreateCommittedResource(&heapDesc, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &resourceDesc, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&myresource));
```

and this is the one for `CreateCommitedResource`:

```
D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES const DefaultHeapProperties =
{
    D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT,
    D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_UNKNOWN,
    D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_UNKNOWN,
    0, 0
};

D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC resource_desc{};
resource_desc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
resource_desc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
//resource_desc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
resource_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
//resource_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
resource_desc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
resource_desc.Width = static_cast<UINT64>(resources.raytracingData.bootstrap_sample_count);
resource_desc.Height = 1;
//resource_desc.Width = /* ... */;
resource_desc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR;
resource_desc.MipLevels = 1;
resource_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;

device->CreateCommittedResource(&DefaultHeapProperties, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &resource_desc, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&myresource));
```

Comment: you need RWStructuredBuffer<T> (where T is your struct), then your limitation is pretty much gone

Comment: @mrvux I've changed it to `RWStructuredBuffer<float>` in my HLSL code, but I'm still getting the same error. Do I need to change something else as well?

Comment: @mrvux Or do I need to use `CreateBuffer` instead of `CreateCommittedResource` here?

Comment: can you post the code for the CreateBuffer /  CreateCommittedResource  part?

Comment: Ah yes indeed you need to create the resource accordingly as well as the view

Answer (score 1):

In order to use more elements, you need to use structuredBuffers,
so in your hlsl code you need to use

```
RWStructuredBuffer<float>
```

Also the code to setup the view is different, this needs to be set as :

```
    D3D12_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc = {};
    uavDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
    uavDesc.Buffer.NumElements = ElementCount; // number of elements you need in your buffer
    uavDesc.Buffer.StructureByteStride = sizeof(float); //size of one element
    uavDesc.Buffer.CounterOffsetInBytes = 0;
    uavDesc.Buffer.Flags = D3D12_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_NONE;
```

To create the resource you can continue using CreateCommittedResource:

```
D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC bufferDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(elementCount * elmentSize , D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_UNORDERED_ACCESS);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'd done previously and it does yield the error quoted in the question. The solution for me was to use `CreateBuffer` instead of `CreateCommitteResource`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I'd be surprised if the provided code i.e. `DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN` didn't work, this is the best solution. It's only typed resources that are limited to 25K

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which supports large buffer is raw buffers.

They are exposed to HLSL as [RWByteAddressBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwbyteaddressbuffer) (read+write access) or [ByteAddressBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-byteaddressbuffer) (read only access) objects. Note you will need byte offsets instead of elements offsets (i.e. multiply element offset by 4), and `asfloat` / `asuint` when loading / storing data in your shaders.

You need to specify `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS` for the format of the buffer, and `D3D12_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_RAW` or `D3D12_BUFFER_SRV_FLAG_RAW` flags when creating the views.

Comment: Does this approach introduce overhead in my shader? I could imagine that the loading operations and the `asfloat` function introduces overhead.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I would expect that overhead to be negative. asfloat/asuint functions are probably free. In DXBC byte code they compile into nothing at all. I expect actual instruction set (after the JIT compiler in the user-mode half of the GPU driver) to be similar to DXBC in that regard. You need load/store instructions for any memory access in shaders. Memory operations through texture views or typed buffer views are generally more expensive because these views can convert types on the fly, while raw buffers always deliver original bytes, probably cheaper.